# Buffer overflow Exercise with scanf?

Tags: assembly, buffer, overflow, scanf

I'm solving an old exam from our university and need help with the following question:

On a 32bit Linux system. we have this assembly, in which `scanf()` is called and we want to achieve an buffer overflow.

Now in the solutions it means, that it would be sufficient if we give a 12byte/char input, so as to overwrite the return address.
However the `%ebx` register stores (I think..) the address of the buffer.
My problem is, that `%ebx = %ebp-8` means we need 16 bytes to overwrite the return address (because 8 bytes buffer + 4 bytes old ebp + 4 bytes return address).

In the description of the exercise is written, that the buffer is only 4 bytes long.

Here is the exercise:

```
    pushl %ebp
    movl  %esp,%ebp
    subl  $0x10,%esp
    pushl %esi
    pushl %ebx
    xorl  %esi,%esi
    leal  0xfffffff8(%ebp),%ebx
    addl  $0xfffffff8,%esp
    pushl %ebx
    pushl $0x8048680
    call  8048434 <_init+0x74> # call scanf
```

Comment: `buffer overflow` by itself doesn't necessarily mean overwriting the return address, so yeah, 12 bytes would overflow the buffer and overwrite old `ebp` (of course 9 bytes is enough for that).

Comment: but unfortunately the solution to the exercise tells, that 12 byte would be enough to overwrite the return address too...

Comment: Assuming it's a string, entering 12 bytes would put the zero terminator in the 13th byte which would indeed overwrite part of the return address at least.

Comment: thats not possible because the exercise says we want to return to address 0x8048571 instead of 0x804856b